How to access local DB visual studio
I recently did an asp.net core 6project and I connected it to the local database, because I wouldn't be working with that many data.
I zipped the whole project  and when I opened it from another computer all the data was gone. Is there anything I can do for the data to show?
I tried add-migration and updating the database but it still wont show
I also did this step: Ensure the file is copied to the output directory: Right-click on the database file in Solution Explorer, select "Properties," and set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always." This ensures that the database file is copied to the output directory when you build your project.

What is the "it" where you "zipped it and .. opened it from another computer"? The ASP.NET project? The database? You need to edit your post and tell us how you did that. You also need to tell us how you "tried add-migration and updating the database".

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a guess, but was the missing data added to the database by running the project?

Normally database does not work like that. If you need the database to be restored somewhere with data, you should export the database. I suggest use SSMS which is straight-forward. And export as a .bacpac file will create a backup with data. When restoring you can just use the import database function
